# Sending request to the controller via ajax removing slashes from namespace?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2, request

```
onclick="loadInlineEditor({
                        class:'<?= get_class($content) ?>', 
                        model_id:<?= $content->id ?>,
                        attribute:'description'
                    })"
```

Output for `get_class($content)` should be `app\models\Page`

But Inside controller this `appmodelsPage` is how I get it back via sending it as AJAX request

AJAX code:-

```
function loadInlineEditor(data) {
        $.ajax({
                url: '<?= Url::toRoute(["//url"]) ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json'
            })
```

Output Code:-

```
Array
(
    [class] => appmodelsPage
    [model_id] => 1
    [attribute] => description
)
```

Comment: Try this :  class:'<?= addslashes(get_class($content)) ?>', Because the \ was an escape characters so you need to escape it before store him in the class properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not ajax that is removing the slashes. It's because the js code generated by php looks like this:

```
loadInlineEditor({
    class:'app\models\Page', 
    model_id: 1,
    attribute:'description'
})
```

But `\` (backslash) character in JS string is used as escape char. If you want to use backslash in JS string you have to escape it by itself as `\\`.

To do that you can use either `addslashes()` php function or `json_encode()`.

```
onclick="loadInlineEditor({
    class:'<?= addslashes(get_class($content)) ?>', 
    model_id:<?= $content->id ?>,
    attribute:'description'
})"
```

The `json_encode` will add the `"` around the string so you don't have to use quotes too.

```
onclick="loadInlineEditor({
    class:<?= json_encode(get_class($content)) ?>, 
    model_id:<?= $content->id ?>,
    attribute:'description'
})"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the **** was an escape characters so you need to escape it before store him in the class properties.

So your code become :

```
onclick="loadInlineEditor({
                        class:'<?= addslashes(get_class($content)) ?>', 
                        model_id:<?= $content->id ?>,
                        attribute:'description'
                    })"
```

In fact the addslashes send **app\models\Page** to the class properties and it save to **app\models\Page**